# IIS 7.0 doesn't allow download of MP4 videos

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, download, mp4

I hosted some `mp4` videos on IIS. Although IIS 7.0 lists the video files, it doesn't allow download of them and a `404 Not Found` is returned.

Comment: how big is the file?  There may be a cap on the size of the download if i remember correctly

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check the MIME Types, you will probably have to add it (MP4) to "allow download".

Comment: +1 - I had to do exactly this last week. Need to add the mime type for media/video IIRC.

Comment: Yes, adding `mp4` as `video/mp4` fixed it.

Comment: For Clear understanding of others...Let me put it step by step Choose the **website** to configure in IIS -> right click Choose **Properties** -> choose **HTTP Headers Tab** -> choose **File Types** under the **MIME Map** section -> choose **New Type** type **.mp4** as the extension and **video/mp4** as the mime type and choose **OK**. if still no change then restart iis.I have done like this in iis 6.0 it works for me.

Comment: Or check here to see how you can do this through web.config: https://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config