# download button cant download mp4 but can .exe

Tags: php, html, sql, iis, video

Ok; I have been trying to figure this out for about 6 hours now I am creating a simple website where you can download videos and applications.

I have a database that stores the titles of the video and the Id of the piece of media it needs to download.

The problem I have is when I try to download an mp4 file format I get a `404` error saying it cannot find the file. If I swap the extension in the code to .exe format, it finds the file and asks if you want to save or run the file like it should.

The browser's URL is shown correctly as it should with both files, yet only the .exe actually works. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

The download buttons code is:

```
<div id="Media_download">
<a href="http://thor/classroom/Downloads/'.$row['media_id'].''.$row['title'].'.mp4" target="_blank">
<img class="Download_Button" src="images/download.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I am running a Windows server 2008 R2 as my test server, and I am using PHP version 5.3

I have the `root directory / downloads folder /this is where my mp4 files and .exe are` as you can see above.

The files' name is displayed as the media_id, title, extension; so for example it would be 
1ccleaner.exe or 2rush.mp4

Comment: Have you verified that the URL matches your expected path? Because a 404 is a file not found.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes they both have identical names and both files are within the downloads folder they both have the correct media id and title within the url but only the .exe is found

Comment: what are you using as webserver?

Comment: as I said in my question I am using windows server 2008 R2 @GeraldSchneider

Comment: windows server is an operating system. you can run any kind of webserver on it. Apache, IIS, NginX, ...

Comment: Your `href` isn't right. If you're actually "echoing" it, then modify your question accordingly. If that's your actually code, it's invalid.

Comment: sorry im new to servers and @GeraldSchneider it is iis

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am currently echoing the code above to the screen but this is part of a variable and the code above would not benefit or change if i put the full code

Comment: I understand. I had to ask @user3387522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you use IIS when you use windows to host your application.
Have you added the correct mime type to your IIS config?

You should add mp4 as video/mp4 in the Mime Map:

Info from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182060/1210773)

1. Choose the website to configure in IIS
2. right click Choose Properties
3. choose HTTP Headers Tab
4. choose File Types under the MIME Map section
5. choose New Type type .mp4 as the extension and video/mp4 as the mime type
6. choose OK.

if still no change then restart iis.

About the download instead of opening in a new tab, html5 has a new download property:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Thank you this is completely correct after I added the mime type to the server and restarted it it allowed me download the file =D

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, the browser is trying to play the mp4 file, rather than prompting the user to download it (as it does with a .exe). It's opening a new window (`target="_blank"`) and then trying to navigate to a location outside your web root (`http://thor/classroom/Downloads...`). If you direct your users to right-click and select 'save as,' then it might work as you expect.

You might find some other helpful information here: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/767b39db-d7ac-458e-856f-c2b2c22316fe/link-to-a-mp4-file-for-download?forum=web)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider what makes no sense ??

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the code I have provided in my question allows me to download a .exe file but will not allow me to download a mp4 file that has identical name and the code has been altered to .mp4 instead of exe what has confused you ?

Comment: @user3387522 I'm talking about the answer by beercodebeer, not your question.

Comment: He's saying the answer that @beercodebeer gave makes zero sense, and he's correct that it makes no sense.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider oh ok I though you meant my question, why does beercodebeer answer not make sense ?

Comment: @user3387522 if I had meant your question, I would have made the comment directly below the question, not under this answer. This is how SO works.

Comment: Browsers treat mp4 files different than exes. Depending on the user's settings and flavor of browser, it might try to play the mp4, or the user's media player may step in and try to play it. In order to save the file, they'll either need to manually select save-as, or you can zip the file that you want downloaded and link to http://thor/.../*.zip. If the file is NOT outside the web root, then that was a misunderstanding on my part (but made sense to me if the browser is then returning a 404 for an otherwise valid path). As Mibsen pointed out, it could very well be a MIME type issue as well.

Comment: Am I the only one that think @beercodebeer is talking sense?

Comment: @beercodebeer you was actually partially correct at the moment the firefox is actually trying to play the file instead of downloading it but in other browsers this is downloaded as a file instead so thank you it looks like the main problem was the mime type as mibsen has said thank you for the help