# cannot access mp4 file on iis7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I tyied to access `mp4` file with its link:`http://www.test.com/test.mp4` on my website, but it failed and the error message is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. My website is written by `asp.net` and run on `iis7.5`. Can any one tell me what Im I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182031/iis-7-0-doesnt-allow-download-of-mp4-videos

Comment: I added  `.mp4 video/mp4` to Mine, and I could download it with `downloader`. But I failed to play it on the browser.

Comment: what is the code that you try to play it ?

Comment: I tried to use `<video src="http://www.test.com/test.mp4"><video/>` to play it, but it didn't work and the error message is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931566/getting-error-in-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset